# C++ and QML : object relations

Tags: qt, c++11, qml

I'm discovering QML.
I have a class MyWindow :

```
class MyWindow : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(int nbMatch READ GetNbMatch NOTIFY matchChangedQMLL)
  Q_PROPERTY(std::vector<Match> match READ GetCalendar NOTIFY matchChangedQMLL)
  ...
}
```

In this object, I have an object that retrieved a set of data with different object types (class Match, Team, ...)

I want to display these information in my QML.

Does I need to make inheritence to QObject for all these classes (Match, Team, ...) ?

Thanks

Comment: yes, you have to derive these classes from `QObject` and register all the custom types to be used in QML. for the lightweight classes you can use [Q_GADGET](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_GADGET) instead of `Q_OBJECT`. Also you have to avoid using `std::vector`. Use [QVariantList](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#QVariantList-typedef) instead. See [Data Type Conversion Between QML and C++](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html) for more info.

Comment: For larger amounts of list- or table like data, i would suggest to use QAbstractItemModel